# Quote within a .CSV data field

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, oledb

Here is my current connection string:

```
string connString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""{0}"";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited\""",Path.GetDirectoryName(csv_file_path));
```

This works fine except I have a few lines of code as follows:

```
"jon","smith","ohio"
"tom","jones","indiana"
"mary","baker "mills","florida
```

The last line has quotes within the field and the field is ending before "mills".  Does anyone have a connection string that can accommodate a quote within a data field?

Thanks!

Comment: Fixing the data to escape the quotes seems like the more straightforward solution; any reason you can't do that instead?

Comment: As what @Jacob mentioned, can you not fix the data in the first place? Also, why are you using a raw string like that as your data source? Could you not read that in with a helper library that parses CSV files, such as CsvHelper?

Comment: you delimiter should be , instead of "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while fixing your source is the most correct answer, I suppose if you really want you can use `var myStr = originalStr.replace(@"""",@"""""");`  this would escape all instances of the quote character.

again, if possible, fix the data.